# Value Error : could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (3,1)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, broadcast

```
class ForwardKinematicsAgent(PostureRecognitionAgent):
    def __init__(self, simspark_ip='localhost',
                 simspark_port=3100,
                 teamname='DAInamite',
                 player_id=0,
                 sync_mode=True):
        super(ForwardKinematicsAgent, self).__init__(simspark_ip, simspark_port, teamname, player_id, sync_mode)
        self.transforms = {n: identity(4) for n in self.joint_names}

        # chains defines the name of chain and joints of the chain
        self.chains = {'Head': ['HeadYaw', 'HeadPitch'],
                       'LArm': ['LShoulderPitch']}
        
        self.link_translation = {'HeadYaw': [0., 0., 126.50], 'HeadPitch':  [0., 0., 0.], 'LShoulderPitch': [0., 98., 100.]}

    def think(self, perception):
        self.forward_kinematics(perception.joint)
        return super(ForwardKinematicsAgent, self).think(perception)

    def local_trans(self, joint_name, joint_angle):
        '''calculate local transformation of one joint

        :param str joint_name: the name of joint
        :param float joint_angle: the angle of joint in radians
        :return: transformation
        :rtype: 4x4 matrix
        '''
        T = identity(4)
        c = cos(joint_angle)
        s = sin(joint_angle)
        if(joint_name.find('Roll') != -1):                #find returns index of searched string or -1 if not found
            R = matrix([[1, 0, 0], [0,c,-s], [0, s, c]])  #if we have roll we have Rx matrix
        if(joint_name.find('Pitch') != -1):    
            R = matrix([[c, 0, s], [0, 1, 0], [-s, 0, c]]) #pitch -> Ry
        if(joint_name.find('Yaw') != -1):
            R = matrix([[c, s, 0], [-s, c, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) #Yaw -> Rz

        T[0:3, 0:3] = R  #insert appropriate rotation matrix in top left of transform matrix
        T[0:3, 3] = self.link_translation[joint_name] #insert the spatial translation of the link in 4th colum of the T-matrix
        return T

    def forward_kinematics(self, joints):
        '''forward kinematics

        :param joints: {joint_name: joint_angle}
        '''
        for chain_joints in self.chains.values():
            T = identity(4)
            for joint in chain_joints:
                angle = joints[joint]
                Tl = self.local_trans(joint, angle)
                T = T * Tl              #matrix multiplication T0_N = T0_1 * T1_2 * T1_3 etc
                self.transforms[joint] = T
```

I am simply trying to replace the three first elements of the 4th column of a 4x4 identity matrix,
but the line   `T[0:3, 3] = self.link_translation[joint_name]` gives me the error in the title.

I don't understand why this line doesn't work because I'm trying to replace 3 elements of a list by 3 elements of another list and in fact when I try just the line   `T[0:3, 3] = [0,1,2]` in a new program it works. So I don't think it is a syntax error

PS : I took out most of the elements of self.chains and self.link_translations because they made it all unreadable and aren't part of the problem I thinl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like making a [mre].

Comment: I was able to test the code after removing the "PostureRecognitionAgent" from the class definition, replacing the "super" by defining the "self.joint_names", and initializing an object and calling the "forward_kinematics" method on it. Overall there were no errors for me. It may be that there is a mistake with one of the self.chains or self.link_translations that you didn't include, there may be no problem at all, or super does something to the matrix that I just don't understand.